# How do I stop the html form on my mobile website in portrait view from floating right to landscape view everytime I click on the input fields?

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile, media-queries

I have tried using float, overflow, clear and yet still my html form continues floating right. My intended outcome is for the html form to remain in portrait on my mobile device when I go to fill out the form.

This is the current  css code for my html form on desktop platform:

```
form 
{
border: 10px solid #D3D3D3;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #D3D3D3;
width: 174px;
height: 306px;
position: absolute;
top: 212px;
left: 1168px;
font-family: "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif";
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
}
.FormHeading
{
text-decoration: underline;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
left: 29px;
}
input[type=text]
{
width: 168px;
}
textarea
{
resize: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
top: -23px;
left: 01px;
width: 173px;
}

input[type=submit]
{
background-color: #ADD8E6;
position: relative;
top: -40px;
left: 121px;
text-align: center;
}
```

This is the current code for my html form on mobile:

```
    <form name = "CommentsForm" action ="Actionpage.php" onsubmit="return       
    validateForm()" method="post">
    <u class = "FormHeading">Send Comment</u><br>
    <br>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    <div style = "position: relative; top: 4px; left: 01px;">
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style = "position: relative; top: -13px; left: 1px;">
     Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style = "position: relative; top: -24px; left:03px;">
    <label for="comment"> Comment:</label></div>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Type commment              
    here" style="height: 69px;">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Send" >
    </form>

This is the css for the html form on my mobile website:

form 
{ 
border: 10px solid #D3D3D3; 
border-radius: 4px;
background: #D3D3D3;
width: 176px;
height: 319px;
position: absolute;
top: 620px; 
left: 91px;
font-family: "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif"; 
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
float: none;
}
.FormHeading
{
text-decoration: underline;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
left: 29px;
}
input[type=text]
{
width: 168px;
float: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus
{
float: none;

}
textarea
{
resize: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
top: -23px;
left: 01px;
width: 173px;
float: none;
}

input[type=submit]
{
background-color: #ADD8E6;
position: relative;
top: -44px;
left: 119px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Please note I have a HTC desire 626 and I am designing my mobile website with this in mind.

Comment: form 
{
    border: 10px solid #D3D3D3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    width: 176px;
    height: 319px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 620px;
    left: 91px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif";
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: none;
}

Comment: The code for my form is now in the question, I really need to get this fixed asap.

Comment: The question cannot be answered as is, because you have only provided the CSS, not the HTML for the form. I can makes guesses - e.g.,  the contents of the form is wider than the form itself and the browser scrolls sideways to keep the whole input field visible that is currently in focus. But you really need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Only then can we work on it.

Comment: I would like to apologise for the original post which was not clear and I have now updated it.  Can anybody help me with the question please?

Comment: You can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) to fix the position on multiple screens. The form has an absolute position and it depends on its first parent that has a relative position. And sometimes scripts affect the styles. If you can provide full code, like parents of the form and your js code we can help better.

Comment: I am currently using media queries for my website and I have tried fixing the issue within the media query  for mobile devices

Comment: I have added the css for my form on desktop, please see the edit in my description.